# Should I let Git use the default branch name? Or is it a good idea to choose it myself?

Tags: git, installation, git-bash

I'm installing Git on my computer for the first time, because I wanted to have a version control of an (almost) failed project from my high school; so that way I can apply things that I learn on that project and share my progress on GitHub (I know, very original).

The thing is that while installing it asks me this question:
[image]

Should I leave it there? Or is it a good idea to choose the name of the branch instead of using Git's default?

Any help would be welcome. I'm not really sure if this is a question worth posting here, but just in case so I don't make something dumb.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can trivially change it later if you care to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you choose really doesn't matter. This only affects the default branch name when you first create a repo by running `git init`.

Once you've initialize a repo, you can instantly change the name of the current branch by running

```
$ git branch -m <new name>
```

and you can always change the default branch name to whatever you want by running

```bash
$ git config --global init.defaultBranch <new name>
```

Comment: BTW, since I made another beginner mistake on stackoverflow, this question is now closed. The only thing keeping me from deleting it is just because I think that this command will be very useful someday and I probably will not remember it straight away.